# Laravel Wherehas in pivot relationship not working and return no data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been create JOIN with eager load with these tables

1. Transactions (**parent** of *transaction_details*)
2. Transaction_details (**child** of *Transaction* and **parent** of *Mutasi_logs* )
3. Mutasi_logs (**child** of *transaction_details*)

to search data on these 3 tables I am Using WhereHas and below is my code :

```
MutasiLog::with([
                  'transaction_detail.transaction',
                  'transaction_detail'
          ])
          ->orWhereHas('transaction_detail', function ($q) use ($search) {
               $q->where('id', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');

               $q->whereHas('transaction',function($q) use ($search){
                   $q->where('description','LIKE','%{$search}%');
               });

          })
          ->where("created_by",'=',Auth::id())
          ->offset($start)
          ->limit($limit)
          ->orderBy($order,$dir)
          ->get();
```

this script not showing anydata (show me data is empty) though the data available on transaction table.

here is my array data :

```
"id" => 20
    "transaction_detail_id" => "07-31730348"
    "mutation_type" => "Db"
    "amount" => "600"
    "saldo" => "31900"
    "created_at" => "2019-09-11 08:46:17"
    "updated_at" => null
    "created_by" => 18
    "updated_by" => null
    "transaction_detail" => array:13 [
      "id" => "07-31730348"
      "transaction_code" => "07"
      "transaction_type" => "Db"
      "account_no" => "11110110087634529"
      "account_no_destination" => "33331758102140796"
      "description" => null
      "amount" => ""
      "saldo" => ""
      "created_at" => "2019-09-11 08:46:17"
      "updated_at" => "2019-09-11 08:46:17"
      "created_by" => 18
      "updated_by" => null
      "transaction" => array:8 [
        "id" => 7
        "code" => "07"
        "description" => "Transfer coin"
        "biaya_admin" => ""
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "created_by" => null
        "updated_by" => null
      ]
    ]
```

Anyone can help me out ? Any mistake on my code above ?

Comment: try changing your orWhereHas to a whereHas

Comment: still not working ... any idea ?

Comment: remove your relations from an array, put them in a comma delimited list instead,

Comment: @MHewison Iam sorry i dont get it ... can you give me the example ?

Comment: with('transaction_detail.transaction') should suffice, your are eager loading the transaction_detail relation here also

Comment: What exactly do you want to find in your example. I mean what must contains in `$search`?

Comment: @Grabatui $search contains data that available on those tables (mutasi_logs,transaction_details,transaction) ...

Comment: also... this line ```$q->where('description','LIKE','%{$search}%');``` will not parse correctly. you need to wrap it like this instead, ```$q->where('description','LIKE',"%{$search}%");```

Comment: @MHewison [SOLVED] thank you mate - Can u put your solution to answer ?

Comment: @MHewison I just changed to `with('transaction_detail.transaction')`  like what you said,thank you ^_^

Comment: You can use where instead of whereHas. Sometimes using gives problem. Let me know if it works